# tufte: two tables on the same page

Tags: floats, minipage, labels, tufte

I have two tables which are about 40% of the page height. Both are related and should stay on the same page. Therefore I put both tables inside a minipage and made it floating.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,cleveref,lipsum}
\usepackage{capt-of}

%% get fullwidth length
\makeatletter
\newlength{\fullwidthlength}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\fullwidthlength}{\@tufte@fullwidth}}
\makeatother

%% custom floating environment
% this puts the minipage on a separate page
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{floatingminipage}{p}{fm}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{floatingminipage}
\begin{minipage}{\fullwidthlength}\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{.95\linewidth}{XX}
    \toprule
    1 & 2 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \captionof{table}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
    \label{tbl:one} 

\vspace*{2cm}   

    \begin{tabularx}{.95\linewidth}{XX}
    \toprule
    1 & 2 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \captionof{table}{Cras sodales pharetra ultrices. Morbi suscipit malesuada neque sit amet laoreet. See \cref{tbl:one}}
    \label{tbl:two} 

\end{minipage} 
\end{floatingminipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The only thing is I cannot get the captions to be of `\marginparwidth` and inside the margin directly under the table. I tried the following

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\latexCaptionOf\captionof
% arguments:
% #1 short caption
% #2 offset
% #3 figure type (table, figure)
% #4 caption text
\RenewDocumentCommand{\captionof}{o O{0mm} m m}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\par\hfill\raisebox{#2}[\height]{%
            \begin{minipage}[b]{\marginparwidth}%
                \IfValueTF{#1}{\latexCaptionOf{#3}[#1]{#4}}%
                {\latexCaptionOf{#3}{#4}}%
            \end{minipage}}%
        \end{minipage}% 
}%
```

but the label does not get resolved anymore and just shows `??`.

[image]

I don't know if my approach is reasonable and any better solutions are welcome. I just need these two table on the same floating page such that labels get resolved.